# How to determine whether a given transistor is NPN or PNP?

Tags: transistors, bjt, identification, npn, pnp

If I have a device which I know is a BJT transistor but I have no other information, how can I determine whether it is NPN or PNP and which pins have C, B & E functionality?

Comment: Is the part number known ? Is it known which pins are `B`, `C` and `E` ?

Comment: If you don't know the part number, you don't know what performance it has so, what would be the point?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a FET, a linear voltage regulator, a thyristor, a temperature sensor or a sound synthesizer? All these devices come in the same three-pin casing. What's the point of this if you can't tell anything about the properties of the transistor afterwards? It's really not like you can just pick any npn transistor and use it in every schematic that demands an npn transistor!

Comment: No one has directly said it, so: There is no standard pin orientation for BJT transistors.  I would use the part number (on the device) to view its datasheet.  If you can't find the datasheet for it, I'd use the measurement methods others have mentioned here.

Comment: If you're asking for a practical, rather than theoretical, answer, there are component testers like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Peak-Electronic-Design-Ltd-dca55/dp/B005NIR8G8) that use various heuristics to identify different kinds of transistors and other semiconductors.

Answer (score 17):

If you **know** the component is a BJT transistor, you can use a diode tester and test the pins pairwise.

- If you find two diodes with a common anode, and no conduction between the two cathodes, then you have a NPN transistor.
- If you find two diodes with a common cathode and no conduction between the two anodes, then you have a PNP transistor.

Other options, if you are not sure the component is a BJT:

- If you find two diodes with a common anode, and some conduction between the two cathodes, the component may be a N-channel J-FET.
- If you find two diodes with a common cathode, and some conduction between the two anodes, the component may be a P-channel J-FET.
- If you find a single diode and no conduction with the third pin, the component may be a MOSFET.

But as others have written in comments, there are many other options for 3-pin packages, such as voltage regulators, SCRs, triacs, darlington assemblies, pairs of diodes, temperature sensors, “adjustable zener”, and probably many others…

Comment: I think you could add the consequence of not **knowing** it is a BJT. (-> JFET) But you can rule out a JFET, if there is no pairwise conduction. JFET will conduct from Drain to Source

Comment: Thanks @tobalt for the suggestion.

Comment: ... and some MOSFETs "remember" their gate voltage for few minutes or seconds after the gate is touched with the probe. This imposes different drain/source resistance.

Comment: I don't know if there are dual diodes in TO-92 package. But if it is a SOT23, then you might have a dual diode also.

Comment: @mkeith Good point, there are some dual varicap diodes in TO-92 package, such as the BB204.

Answer (score 9):

The method dscribed by @user2233709 works to find the base and to determine if the device is PNP or NPN.

Which is C (collector) and which is E (Emitter) and a very rough indication of Beta can be determined as follows.

- To differentiate between collector and emitter assume one of to possible terminals is E (Emitter), connect a 1M - 10M resistor from B (Base) to the presumed Collector and measure the presumed CE "resistance" with an Ohm meter using appropriate polarity, i.e. when testing for the NPN positive (red) lead probe is on C pin and the negative (black) one is on the E pin, whereas when testing for PNP the colours/polarities are reversed.
- NOW assume other candidate is collector and repeat.
- The lower CE resistance indicates the actual Collector-Emitter provided it has correct ohm test polarity stated above.
  Difference is usually significant. Lower resistance indicates higher Beta.

You can use a wet (licked) pair of fingers between CB as the resistor. It works!
So you need only an Ohmmeter and some wet fingers to determine which is case, collector and emitter, whether NPN or PNP and a rough indication of Beta. :-)

Comment: @memek, you've done quite a bit of editing to Russell's answer some of which is incorrect. You have assigned "red lead probe is on C pin ..."  but that will only work for one transistor type. Russell's "*... using appropriate polarity ...*" was deliberate and covers both NPN and PNP. "Emitter" and "collector" are not proper nouns so they don't get capitalised.  It's rather unusual to ask a basic question and then make edits to an answer from a guy with 138k reputation.

Comment: @Memek The technical portions of Transistor's comments (eg appropriate polarity vs red lead and capitalisation are both completely correct. Having people point out such factual matters is how we learn.

Comment: @memek - you were advised on May 22nd that some of your editing of my answer was technically incorrect. You would have been able to establish that this advice was correct. I am surprised that tou did not edit the question to correct your error. I have now corrected the section concerned.